# Transforming setences containing obwohl/weil to trotz/wegen

Tags: standard-german

I want to transform the following sentences containing the below connectors 
trotz/wegen

1a) Ich kann heute nicht zu dir kommen, weil ich keine Zeit habe.
(mit wegen)

1b) Ich kann heute wegen des Zeitmangels nicht zu dir kommen.

2) Ich habe die Prüfung nicht bestanden, obwohl ich viel gelernt habe.

Question 1. Is the sentence **1b)** gramatically correct and does it convey the same meaning as sentence **1a)**?

Question 2. How do I transform the **sentence 2)** to a sentence containing only the connector **trotz**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1a: It's correct, but stylistically not very nice, you'd better write: "wegen Zeitmangels" (without "des"). Question 1b: It does convey the same meaning, but the original is much more common.

Question 2: "Trotz des vielen Lernens habe ich die Prüfung nicht bestanden."

Maybe the point of the exercise was to force you to use the genitive case.